# WebGL not working in PhoneGap Android KitKat

Tags: android, cordova, webgl, cordova-chrome-app

I'm trying to render some WebGL in my PhoneGap/Cordova app but I'm having no luck.

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
var gl = canvas.getContext("webgl") || canvas.getContext("experimental-webgl");
if (!gl) {
    console.log('WebGL not supported');
}
```

The `gl` variable is always null.

I've tried with a OnePlus One and a Nexus 5 which are both Android KitKat v4.4.4 Chrome 38.

The same code works fine on iOS8 and on a desktop.

The code works on a normal webpage loaded in chrome on those devices. So does http://get.webgl.org/

I've even tried using [CCA](https://github.com/MobileChromeApps/mobile-chrome-apps/blob/master/README.md) which uses crosswalk to bundle Chrome into the app.

I've tried Googling bug I'm flooded with people having problems from when devices didnt support it (iOS < v8 and Android < v4.4).

I'm thinking that it might be something that I have to enable in the build chain.

Thank you in advance.

Glen

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've figured it out with some [help](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=354841#c53).

Even though I have Chrome 38 installed, the WebView is actually not using the installed chrome version but another version that ships with the OS and doesn't auto update.

The WebView is actually Chrome 33 which [doesn't support WebGL](https://developer.chrome.com/multidevice/webview/overview).

When Android L comes out, it will support WebGL in the WebView which will automatically update too.

In regards to the CCA version, it bundles Chrome 37 which supports WebGL. It works on devices that don't have [blacklisted GPUs](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about/faq.html#Canvas-and-WebGL-support). If you follow [these instructions](https://crosswalk-project.org/documentation/about/faq.html#Canvas-and-WebGL-support) it tells you that you can make it ignore the blacklist and run on all devices but might have unstable results.

Comment: webviews are not related to the browser on the device, they are packaged with the SDK.

Comment: @DawsonLoudon Yeah you're right. I made a bad assumption. Android L's WebView will be updateable from the Play store though.

Comment: Yes, I read that. They are starting to bundle more parts of the SDK into play services so that they can be updated. This is a great move by Google

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use WebGL on Android 4.0+ Ludei (http://ludei.com) has a project called WebView+ that allows you to use the latest Chromium project on Android. The drawback is that 15Mb are added to your final APK. You can test it using the CocoonJS Launcher App: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ideateca.cocoonjslauncher&hl=es where you can point to a URL (even use a QRCode so you do not have to type the whole URL on a mobile device) or even upload a whole ZIP file with your project to test it off-line.